# qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to displayerror while using OpenCV on ec2 ubuntu server 20.0

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, xcb

I am trying to run Tesseract Ocr code as mentioned here
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/
on ec2 ubuntu server 20.0.

I am facing an error on:

```
cv2.imshow("Text Detection", output)
```

The error is as follows:

> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

> Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc.

> Aborted (core dumped)

I know this line of code would open a window to display the image of detected output ,but that window is not showing up.Please help with the error.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because there was no UI to open up a window and show the image.

A quick fix will be to save and download the image. And view locally.

Another way is to setup a XServer and enable X11 forwarding via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Depends: libgl1 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libglx-mesa0 but it is not going to be installed
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (= 2.24.32-4ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: gir1.2-gtk-2.0 (= 2.24.32-4ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgtk2.0-common but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libx11-dev (>= 2:1.0.0-6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxext-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxinerama-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxi-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxrandr-dev (>= 2:1.2.99) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxcursor-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxfixes-dev (>= 1:3.0.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxcomposite-dev (>= 1:0.2.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxdamage-dev (>= 1:1.0.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxml2-utils but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: debhelper but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
```

In my past experience, pycharm can do local visualization, but sometimes it will go wrong, is this related to the pycharm version or is it related to the remote server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).